# Не работает сортировка в dataTables

Tags: jquery

Использую библиотеку таблицы.

```
<script src="<?echo base_url()?>js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?echo base_url()?>css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#table').dataTable({

                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
            });
        });
    </script>
<h1>Список заявок</h1>
<table id="table" class="images_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="124px">Дата</th>
                <th width="173px">ФИО</th>
                <th>Адрес</th>
                <th>Телефон</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Тип оплаты</th>
                <th>Доставлено</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($order as $item):?>


                <tr class="row" data-id="<?echo $item['id'];?>">
                    <td><?echo $item['date']?></td>
                    <td><?echo $item['fio']?></td>
                    <td><?echo $item['address']?></td>
                    <td><?echo $item['phone']?></td>
                    <td><?echo $item['email']?></td>
                    <td><?echo $item['payment']?></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>


            <? endforeach;?>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Не работает параметр `"order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]`. Документация взята [отсюда](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order).

Может что то неправильно пишу?

Comment: можете небольшой пример как это у вас работает на jsfiddle сделать? с примером данных

Comment: а так же добавьте какую версию библиотеки используете

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, натолкнули на правильную мысль, старую версию использовал, поэтому и делалось так.

Comment: то есть проблема больше не воспроизводится? в таком случае стоит удалить вопрос